# Кнопки на второй форме не реагируют на нажатие

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer

Я хочу  создать приложение, в котором есть два окна. 
В каждом окне есть по две кнопки.

При нажатии одной кнопки на первой форме выводится в консоль слово **`"Forward"`**, при нажатии  второй выводится вторая форма.

Во втором окне при нажатии на одну из кнопок должно просто выводиться сообщение.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from First_window import *
from Second_window import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_First_window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.download_button.clicked.connect(self.handler)
        self.ui.import_button.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)

    def handler(self):
        print("Forward!!!")

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Second_window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
 #       Second_window.hide()
        self.window.show()


class MySecond(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=MyWin):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Second_window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.save_button.clicked.connect(self.handler2)

    def handler2(self):
        print("STOPPP!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

К сожалению во второй форме кнопка не нажимается...
Я пытался сделать следующие изменения:

```
def openWindow(self): 
   self.window = MySecond() 
   self.window.show()
```

получил ошибку:

> `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)`
> TypeError: descriptor `'__init__'` requires a 'sip.simplewrapper' object but received a 'MySecond'

---

Пытался изменить:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
```

на

```
QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
```

и

```
class MySecond(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=MyWin):
```

на

```
class MySecond(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
```

Никакого прогресса. Как решить данную задачу?

---

**First_window.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_First_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, First_window):
        First_window.setObjectName("First_window")
        First_window.resize(605, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(First_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 431, 101))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.download_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.download_button.setObjectName("download_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.download_button)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.import_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.import_button.setObjectName("import_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.import_button)
        self.table_for_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_for_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 431, 201))
        self.table_for_data.setRowCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setObjectName("table_for_data")
        First_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(First_window)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        First_window.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(First_window)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        First_window.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(First_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(First_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, First_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        First_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("First_window", "MainWindow"))
        self.download_button.setText(_translate("First_window", "dowload files"))
        self.import_button.setText(_translate("First_window", "import and interpolate"))
```

**Second_window.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Second_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, Second_window):
        Second_window.setObjectName("Second_window")
        Second_window.resize(605, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Second_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 431, 101))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.save_button.setObjectName("save_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.save_button)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.import_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.import_button.setObjectName("import_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.import_button)
        self.table_for_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_for_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 431, 201))
        self.table_for_data.setRowCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setObjectName("table_for_data")
        Second_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Second_window)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Second_window.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Second_window)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Second_window.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Second_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Second_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, Second_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Second_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("Second_window", "Saving"))
        self.save_button.setText(_translate("Second_window", "save in csv"))
        self.import_button.setText(_translate("Second_window", "import and interpolate"))
```

Comment: опубликуйте модули `First_window.py` и `Second_window.py`

Comment: Опубликовал код. Как просто файл отправить -пока не разобрался

Answer (score 1):

спросите, если что-то будет не понятно:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from First_window import Ui_First_window
class Ui_First_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, First_window):
        First_window.setObjectName("First_window")
        First_window.resize(605, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(First_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 431, 101))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.download_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.download_button.setObjectName("download_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.download_button)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.import_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.import_button.setObjectName("import_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.import_button)
        self.table_for_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_for_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 431, 201))
        self.table_for_data.setRowCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setObjectName("table_for_data")
        First_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(First_window)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        First_window.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(First_window)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        First_window.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(First_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(First_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, First_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        First_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("First_window", "MainWindow"))
        self.download_button.setText(_translate("First_window", "dowload files"))
        self.import_button.setText(_translate("First_window", "import and interpolate"))
        
#from Second_window import Ui_Second_window
class Ui_Second_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, Second_window):
        Second_window.setObjectName("Second_window")
        Second_window.resize(605, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Second_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 431, 101))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.save_button.setObjectName("save_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.save_button)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.import_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.import_button.setObjectName("import_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.import_button)
        self.table_for_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_for_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 431, 201))
        self.table_for_data.setRowCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_for_data.setObjectName("table_for_data")
        Second_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Second_window)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Second_window.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Second_window)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Second_window.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Second_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Second_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, Second_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Second_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("Second_window", "Saving"))
        self.save_button.setText(_translate("Second_window", "save in csv"))
        self.import_button.setText(_translate("Second_window", "import and interpolate"))


class MySecond(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Second_window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.handler2)
        
    def handler2(self):
        print("STOPPP!!!")
        

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_First_window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.download_button.clicked.connect(self.handler)
        self.import_button.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
        
    def handler(self):
        print("Forward!!!")
        
    def openWindow(self):
        self.mySecond = MySecond()
        self.mySecond.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас разберусь!!! Спасибо!!! И еще раз спрошу

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: У меня все таки такой вопрос - для понимания.

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин какой у вас вопрос?

Comment: Все работает,спасибо огромное! НО! super().__init__() - что делает? Это раз .     def __init__(self): -что делает данная функция. parent=None - в каком случае писать.

Comment: Я новичок,да,вопросы могут быть совсем тупыми

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин о функции `super()` вы можете много найти в интернете, например https://realpython.com/python-super/ .  Виджет без родителя - это ОКНО. Так как в вашем примере пока речь идет об окнах, то вам не нужно передавать никакой родительский объект, т.е. ` parent=None` вам пока не нужно.